# How to extract .iso file with Powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an iso file which needs to be extracted through powershell script.

do we have any solution that is applicable in Powershell 2.0 as well?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a third party software for this. You can do it with 7Zip like this:

```
7z.exe x -y -o C:\OutputDirectory X:\YOURISOFILE.iso
```

where

> ```
> x  (Extract with full paths) command
> -o (set Output directory) switch
> -y (assume Yes on all queries) switch
> ```

Comment: If you insist on using PowerShell directly, you could use the [DiscUtils library](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils). If you really, really want to, I suppose it's possible to re-implement a disk image reader in PowerShell itself using .Net classes, but that's not just reinventing the wheel, it's reinventing the wheelwright.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with something like [`DiscUtils`](https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils), which compiles against .NET 2.0 and is therefore usable in OOB PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7.

1. Download/clone DiscUtils
2. Build the entire solution in Visual Studio or using msbuild with default options
3. Import the .NET 2.0 version of the `DiscUtils.Iso9660` assembly and start extracting:

---

```
$isoPath = "C:\path\to\image.iso"
$destination = "C:\Output"

# Import DiscUtils.Iso9660 lib
Add-Type .\DiscUtils\Library\DiscUtils\bin\Release\net20\DiscUtils.Iso9660.dll

# Open a filestream to the ISO
$isoStream = (Get-Item $isoPath).OpenRead('Open')

# Create a CDReader to read the disc image
$reader = [DiscUtils.Iso9660.CDReader]::new($isoStream, $true)

# Enumerate all directories and create in destination:
$reader.GetDirectories('\', '*', 'AllDirectories') |Foreach-Object {
    $null = mkdir (Join-Path $destination $_)
}

# Enumerate all files and copy them to the destination
$reader.GetFiles('\', '*.*', 'AllDirectories') |ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $newFile = New-Item (Join-Path $destination $_) -ItemType File
        $newFileStream = $newFile.OpenWrite()
        $isoFileStream = $reader.OpenFile($_, 'Open')
        $isoFileStream.CopyTo($newFileStream)
        $newFileStream.Close()
    }
    finally {
        $isoFileStream.Dispose()
        $newFileStream.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with following command `Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "*.ISO"`

With that command you can mount disk image for further actions.'
You can use copy action commands after you mount the image with the above command

`$ sudo cp *File Name* /*Location*/` to copy files

`$ sudo cp -r *folder names* /*location*/` to recursive copy directories

After you're done with things `Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "*.ISO"` will dismount the image

Comment: `Mount-DiskImage` ships with Windows 8 and up, so won't help in PowerShell 2.0 (== Windows 7) :-/

Comment: it will mount files in the iso to the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

For 64bit:

```
%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe x -y -o"C:\OutputDirectory" "C:\YOURISOFILE.iso"
```

For 32bit:

```
%ProgramFiles(X86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe x -y -o"C:\OutputDirectory" "C:\YOURISOFILE.iso"
```

The output directory has to be without space!